# best way to accept the enter key for jquery input focus/select/blur?

Tags: jquery, input

The following jsfiddle ...  **http://jsfiddle.net/mqVUU/**  ... is a simple input field UI tweak. The goals are:

- on focus, enlarge the input (via animate)
- on focus, select current input content
- when 'enter' is pressed in the input, blur the input
- on blur, shrink the input

Here's the script so far ...

```
$('input').on({
    focus: function(){
        $(this).animate({'width':200}, 300, 'easeInOutBack');
        $(this).select();
    },
    keydown: function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).blur();
        }
    },
    blur: function(){
        $(this).animate({ 'width':100}, 300, 'easeInOutBack');
        $('#result').html( $(this).val() );
    }
});
```

Can anyone help with these questions ...

1. If I put it in the `animate()` callback, anything the user types while the animation is occurring gets overwritten, which is problematic. So what's the best way to get the `select()` working properly?
2. Is the `keydown` parameter really the only way to accept `enter` as a trigger??

Thanks for any pointers :)

Comment: _"Why isn't the select() working?"_ - It worked for me using your fiddle in FF. _"Is the_ `keydown` _parameter really the only way to accept enter as a trigger"_ - Well there's key _up..._

Comment: A round about way if you dont want to use the keyCode (13) in your code is wrapping it in a form, and handling the form's submit event.

Comment: @techfoobar - Does that work on multi-field forms?

Comment: @nnnnnn - Not unless some extra code to check the last focused element. OR an even uglier way would be wrapping each element (for which we need to capture return key) inside individual forms..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari), a simple .select() doesn't always work, because the default action for mouseup is to clear the selection. So you need to add this handler:

```
mouseup: function(e) {
           e.preventDefault(); 
        }
```

As far as the keydown -- that is the best way to do it. There are others, but they won't give you any advantage.

Comment: nailed it. that eliminates the need to `select()` via callback, and this is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mqVUU/5/ ... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1) Insert select on animation complete:

```
$(this).animate({'width':200}, 300, 'easeInOutBack', function(){
    $(this).select();
});
```

2) If you want to blur input - yes.

Comment: You totally answered the question ... I've just clarified it a bit. Having tried the callback earlier (see http://jsfiddle.net/mqVUU/4/), at least in Chrome, the animation messes up the `select()`... do you have this problem also?

Comment: Yes. It seems that problem is occured in some browsers because of changing input dimensions while text inside is selected.